# HyperLink moves when hovering over menu item.

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a horizontal navigation list for my MVC web application. And each time I hover on a menu Item the Jquery shows the background image and hides it when the mouse leaves the menu Item. However when I place my mouse on the menu Item it moves the hyperlink from within the menu item. I have made a pretty bad version with a jFiddle but  still can repent my problem: [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/CHhW3/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="navlist"> <a href="@Url.Content("~")" id="current"></a>
        @*<li><a href="/Product/">Products</a></li>*@
        <div style="margin-left: 37px;">
            <div class="Aboutbg">
                <div class="About"></div>
            </div> <a href="#" class="aboutus">Aboutus</a>

            <div class="Aboutstar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
    background: url(../Images/Template%20Images/MenuBanner.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -17px;
    margin-top: 65px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 102%;
}
#navlist {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 360px;
}
#navlist a {
    padding: 10px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    z-index: 2;
}
#current {
    background-image: url(../Images/Template%20Images/HomeIcon.png);
    height: 15px;
    width: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#next {
    height: 2px;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 3px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 22px;
    color: #666666;
    font: 18px/27px'OpenSansExtrabold', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 70%;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.Aboutbg {
    background-image: url(../Images/Template%20Images/aboutbg.png);
    padding: 4px;
    width: 94px;
    height: 25px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.About {
    background-image: url(../Images/Template%20Images/About_usIcon.png);
    height: 2px;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 3px;
    float: left;
    margin-left:2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.Aboutstar {
    background-image: url(../Images/Template%20Images/starIcon.png);
    height: 2px;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 3px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 19px;
    margin-left:-17px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.aboutus {
    height: 2px;
    width: 3px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top: 9px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".aboutus").mouseover(function () {
        $(".Aboutbg").show();
        $(".About").show();
        $(".Aboutstar").hide();

    });

    $(".aboutus").mouseout(function () {
        $(".Aboutbg").hide();
        $(".Aboutstar").show();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the div `.Aboutbg` hidden and, on hover this is shown with

```
$(".aboutus").mouseover(function () {
    $(".Aboutbg").show();
    ....
```

This appears in the HTML *before* the `.aboutus` link causing it to "jump" to the right.

Maybe a better way (if you're looking for a mouseover effect) would be to apply the styles from `.Aboutbg` to the button, but in  CSS `:hover` state - thus removing the need for the jQuery?

Comment: Unfotunately this doesnt work because I have to hide two other images you can see from the jQuery. I have it working on another version of this website but im coding it differently here.